# How much should I help the new person in my old job role?

Tags: relationships, previous-employer

I work for a very large organization.

I left one subset of the organization, such as a division, we'll call A, and went to another such subset (such as division) that we'll call B.

In any event, someone from A has taken over my job duties there, and is asking me several questions.

I have conflicting feelings:

```
i) My chief duty is to my new job, B.

ii) I want to be helpful to A.
```

**Question:**
How do I gracefully navigate this situation, so I keep everyone happy, as there could be 'feedback paths' between A and B.

I have been given good reviews in my new job, B.

Comment: What is a subset?

Comment: @Ertai87, a subset in math is a portion of or all of a set and could include an empty set.  In this context, it's a "proper" subset, meaning both are smaller units within the larger whole.  Business terminology for organizations include divisions and so forth.  I edited the question to try to clarify this, as I was using mathematical, not business terminology.

Comment: Why don't you ask your manager how much assistance you should provide?

Comment: @joeqwerty -- that's a delicate issue, hence the question.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Are the words "team", "department", "org", "project group" etc insufficient?

Comment: @Ertai87, I wanted to keep it very vague and general, for anonymity

Comment: @JosephDoggie it may seem delicate but it should not be. You moved division, you are requested to cross training someone in that division. Unless there is an internal-division feud going on, or division budget conflicts, this is standard business practice and neither manager should not be bothered

Comment: I don't think any of @Ertai87's terms would give away any information that would compromise your anonymity.  Those are the expected generic terms

Comment: Why is it a "delicate issue" to ask your manager? In any reasonable organization, managers would welcome that you signal this and ask how to handle it. Also, in most organizations, cooperation across department/division boundaries will happen (though sometimes there may be some additional bureaucratic hassle if they want to cross-charge your hours to your previous department/division, which is why your manager should be aware).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since A & B are both part of the same overall organisation the answer is essentially - help A as much as you can so long as doing so doesn't detriment B.

If the amount of support A needs is  reaching the point where it's starting to impact on your work for B then you'll need to make a call as to whether you approach your manager at B to say that you need to do some additional knowledge transfer to A and you're going to need to take X hours time to do that or you have to decline to help A further and cite that you've got to focus on your work at B.

The third option would be to explain to your replacement at A that you'd be more than happy to help but since you are now working for B you suggest that they ask *their* manager at A to seek approval from *your* manager at B to spare you for additional training time. Doing this gets you off the hook of having to ask your manager to allow you to do the work - but it increases visibility of these issues which your counterpart at A might not want to do. It also adds an additional bureaucratic overhead, which if the support you need to give is small might be excessive.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to know is how much time your own management wants you to spend on that vs your other obligations. The only way to determine that is to ask your manager, I''m afraid, sensitive or not. It's up to them to negotiate that with the other person's manager.

Comment: Yep manager from org A and B can have a chat, figure out how must time you can spend in training. A and B are the same company so something that works for all should be easy to figure out

Answer (score 1):

First you need to accept that you cannot keep everyone happy given that you moved from a job that you clearly no longer wanted to do to a job that you want to do and you have someone dragging you back to the job you do not want to do. So either you are left unhappy by helping with a job you do not want to do or the new person is left unhappy by you refusing to assist in the old job.

So the question becomes, who do you want to leave more unhappy? You or the new person? Has management provided you with any expectation of you assisting the new person?

At the end of the day you are the only person who can decide how much time and energy you are willing to put into training the new person to do your old job. I find it reasonable to answer the occasional general question but that can quickly escalate into feeling like you are back in your old role. Given that you want to be helpful, then establish some boundaries for yourself and offer assistance up to those boundaries. If the new person attempts to cross them then let him/her know that you are not able to assist in more in-depth questions and possibly point them in the right direction to another resource, etc.